# Python compare Dictionary Key on condition

Tags: python

I have the following python dictionary which I made sorted in order to find their difference

```
k={0: 2, 1: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1}
```

Now I want to compare dictionary keys in such a way that, if the dictionary key difference is equal to 1, I want to add two values of  dictionaries.
I tried the approach of next and Iter but I am not getting the expected Item sadly.

The dictionary key ranges from 0-100 only

required output if possible in array [3,3,2,2] i.e difference of 0 and 1 is 1 so value of 0 and 1 is 3(sum of 1 and 0 value) and same for 3,4

Comment: Your attempt is just to print all the keys in the dictionary. And shouldn't the result be `[3, 3, 2, 2]`?

Comment: Yeah sorry for that your output guess is correct

Comment: Trying to clarify the question: if the dictionary has $n$ elements, should the output have $n-1$ elements or $n/2$ elements? Maybe it will be helpful to add another example with more details about how the expected result is calculated.

Comment: Dictionary key range is 0-100 only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly:

```py
k={0: 2, 4: 1, 1: 1, 6: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1}
keys = sorted(k.keys())  # [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

result = []
for i in range(1, len(keys)):
    if keys[i] - keys[i-1] == 1:
        result.append(k[keys[i]] + k[keys[i-1]])

print(result)  # [3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Please remember, that if not all dictionary keys are always numbers, above code will not work - you'd have to catch `TypeError` in `keys = sorted(k.keys())` line